# excel.link R package forcing Excel to Calculations Automatic

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have an R script that, among other things, loops through a list of Excel binary files (*.xlsb, a lot of predefined content inside, Calculations set to *Manual*) and pastes a data.frame in a specific range and then changes the value of some other cells in a different worksheet.

As files are *.xlsb, I have implemented a solution using the excel.link package.
The package itself works fine but there is one major problem: as soon as it writes something into an open workbook, it changes the calculations of that workbook to *Automatic*.

This is such a big problem because the spreadsheets themselves are very big, with many calculations and worksheets happening. It takes between 15 and 45 secs to re-calculate the workbook. To make things worse, the workbook recalculates everytime R (through excel.link) writes data into it. In my case, for every workbook I print data in 3 different places. So this slows me down a lot.

Ideally I would like to be able to control this aspect, i.e. set calculations to automatic only right before saving the file, so that the workbook calculates only once. --similar to the XLConnect package *setForceFormulaRecalculation*, which however does not support *.xlsb.

Otherwise, any sort of workaround would be welcome.

I am pasting below a few lines of my code, however I do not believe it's very relevant.

```
xl.workbook.open(paste0(bs_path,"\\UAT Results Summary_Wave1.xlsb"))
xl.sheet.activate("Input - Subtotals Liab")
xls = xl.get.excel()
rng1 = xls[["Activesheet"]]$Cells(free_cell,11)
wrt=xl.write(Smmry,rng1,row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
xl.sheet.activate("Instructions")
xlrc[a13]=as.numeric(jobstep)
xlrc[b13]=as.numeric(jobstep)
xl.workbook.save(paste0(dest_path,"\\UAT Results Summary_",fund_short,"_",jobstep), file.format=xl.constants$xlExcel12)
xl.workbook.close()
```

Let me know if you would like to see more code.

Please note I am not considering converting to xlsx and back to xlsb at the moment. Speed is of the essence for this script.
Also please note that I am not able to use RExcel or any other Excel add-ons, at the moment at least.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For speed `excel.link` disable automatic recalculation before every output to Excel and set calculation to automatic after output. I fix this behavior in the next release. Recalculation status will be restored to the previous state rather than automatic recalculation.
By now you can try to set manual recalculation after each data exchange as in the following example:

```
app = xl() 
xl[a1] = 42
app[["Calculation"]] = xl.constants$xlCalculationManual
```

**UPDATE 2018.07.09:**
Another approach is live-patching package code. Try the snippet below. It works for me.

```
library(excel.link)
set_excel_state = function(app){
    app[["Statusbar"]] = ""
    app[["Screenupdating"]] = TRUE
    app[["Calculation"]] = xl.constants$xlCalculationManual
    invisible(NULL)    
}

assignInNamespace("make.me.slow", set_excel_state, ns = "excel.link")
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.
However, this does not seem to work. I think the Calculations are set to Automatic instantly, so that when pasting data, it instantly recalculates the spreadsheet and only then it sets Calculations to Manual. 
This does not help on the 2nd or 3rd data exchange either, as the same thing is happening.
I am using the following code:
`xls = xl.get.excel()`
`rng1 = xls[["Activesheet"]]$Cells(2,11)
 wrt=xl.write(Smmry,rng1,row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
 xls[["Calculation"]] = xl.constants$xlCalculationManual`

Comment: Just to be more precise:
The spreadsheet starts with Calculations set to Manual and ends up having Calculations set to Manual; but on each data exchange it still recalculates the spreadsheet, so no time / speed benefit is obtained.

Comment: Re: Update
That works like a charm ! Thank you so much.